# Django Query Set Results

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm looking to run a query in django and return an entire rows worth of data.  In SQL I'd write "SELECT * FROM SAMPLE WHERE PK=1".  How do a run a filter in django but still return the entire row of data?  I understand the filter but its only returning a single value not the entire row of data. Is my issue related to the filter, how I interact with the query set, or a problem with how I've put together my model? Example below...

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    PID=UUIDField()
    ClientID=models.TextField()
    Key=models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ClientID



output=Sample.objects.filter(PK=1)

Results:<Sample: ClientID1>
```

Comment: Can't you just reference the fields thus: `output.PID`, `output.ClientID`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Resolve your row into a `Sample` object (assuming a unique one exists), use

```
output = Sample.objects.get(pk=1)
```

You can then access its fields as you would any other object: `object.PID`, `object.ClientID`, `object.Key` in your case. You might wish to catch the case where no matching row was returned with:

```
try:
    output = Sample.objects.get(pk=1)
except Sample.DoesNotExist:
    # Do something about non-existent row
```